# Error on clickonce update “Manifest XML signature is not valid”

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, deployment, clickonce, xml-signature

Our currently distributed software works on framework 3.5. We are about to give an update to framework 4.6 now. In clickonce auto update, we get an error -

[image]

The error in details are -

- Exception reading manifest : the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
- Manifest XML signature is not valid.
- SignatureDescription could not be created for the signature algorithm supplied.

> The issue I suppose is that 3.5 support for **sha1** algorithm, and in
>   the new setup of 4.6 the algorithm used is **sha256**. Is there any
>   way to solve this issue?
>   I am using Visual Studio 2013 update 5.